# How do I change the function to open a weblink?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Currently, I am trying to change the button's function to open a weblink when the if statement is true and remove the actions currently assigned to the button. Could someone please help me achieve this!

```
      public Button() {
       rollButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            int i1 = (int) (random() * 6);
            roll1.setIcon(icon[i1]);
            int i2 = (int) (random() * 6);
            roll2.setIcon(icon[i2]);
            int i3 = (int) (random() * 6);
            roll3.setIcon(icon[i3]);

            if (i1 + i2 + i3 == 15) {
                rollButton.setText("Congratulations!");


            }
            else
            {
                rollButton.setText("Roll");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://example.com/"))
```

PS: This is all Java, by the way, so I'm not sure why your question has a "javascript" tag.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! Do you have any idea of how I can change the button function?

Comment: Just put the above code right after where you have `rollButton.setText("Congratulations!");`. Oh, and please up-vote my answer if it works for you. :)

Comment: It works, but when I click the button it carries on generating values and setting the labels as icons. I do not want this to happen once the weblink is opened!

Comment: It wasn't clear what you meant by "change the button function", and I'm still a bit fuzzy on that. You mean change it so it basically doesn't do anything anymore? Change it so it will re-open the web page if clicked again? Depending on what you mean, you could just disable the button once the game is won (`rollButton.setEnabled(false);`), or add a flag like `gameWon`, set it to `true` when the game is won, test if `gameWon` is true before rolling and setting icons again.

Comment: Thank you, you have answered my question. Sorry for not being very clear I am quite new to Java and have just joined this forum!